# At what number of variables does provability in Peano Arithmetic differ from truth in the standard model?

Tags: model-theory, peano-axioms

Let our language be $\{+,\cdot,<,0,1\}$. Let $T_n$ be the set of of true statements in that language (true in the standard model $\mathbb{N}$) that have at most $n$ bound variables and no other variables. Let $P_n$ be the set of statements in that language that are provable in first-order Peano arithmetic that have at most $n$ bound variables and no other variables.

Let me give some examples. $0<1$ is in both $P_0$ and $T_0$. $(\forall x) (0+x)=x$ is in $P_1$ and $T_1$. Also, duplicate variables are counted more than once, like for example $((\forall x) x=x \vee (\forall x) (x+0)=x)$ would be in $T_2$, not $T_1$.

Certainly, $P_n$ is a subset of $T_n$. Also, $P_0 = T_0$. My question is, what is the least $n$ such that $P_n$ is a proper subset of $T_n$?

Comment: @AlvaroP. But my quantifiers are not bounded.

Comment: I don't know much about PA, but I think $T_1=P_1$ as well. It suffices to consider formulas of the form $\forall x\varphi(x)$, where $\varphi$ is a disjunction of atomic formulas and their negations, i.e. up to equivalence, $P(x)>0$ and $P(x)=0$, where $P$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients. Since such a polynomial can change sign only a finite number of times, I think PA should be able to decide the truth of such statements (it's enough for it to be able to prove that a given polynomial does not change signs past a certain point, and then this reduces to a bounded quantifier).